# Mono - Start process with the newest CLR version

Tags: c#, .net, mono, clr

I have a mono application running on Windows. The application itself is running on .NET 3.5. How can I start a different application built with .NET 4.0 using Process.Start? I need to use UseShellExecute=false, because I need to redirect IO streams.

This should be possible with mono by doing something like this: "mono.exe myapp.exe", is there perhaps a solution with Microsoft CLR?

I'm currently getting exception EntryPointNotFoundException.

Comment: So what happens when you try to start the target application using the windows shell (from explorer, for instance)? Does it fail in a similar way?

Comment: It starts normally from windows shell, but fails to start from .NET 3.5 application with Process.Start.